# Alteração de usuário não funciona, está duplicando dado no banco

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Implementei o spring security no meu projeto, já consigo registrar novos usuários e fazer login/logout. Agora estou tentando fazer a edição dos dados desse usuário, quando eu clico em salvar, ele duplica os dados no banco, e como meu redirect é pra página "Minha conta" ele encontra dois registros do mesmo "username" e retorna o erro abaixo:

javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2

Segue código:

RepositoryUsuario:

```
public interface RepositoryUsuario extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long>{

Usuario findByEmail(String email);
Usuario findByUsername(String username);

}
```

ServicoUsuario:

```
@Service
public class ServiceUsuario {

@Autowired
private RepositoryUsuario repUsuario;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public Usuario encontrarPorUsername(String Username) {
    return repUsuario.findByUsername(Username);
}

public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
    usuario.setSenha(passwordEncoder.encode(usuario.getSenha()));
    repUsuario.save(usuario);
}

public Usuario getOne(Long id) {
    return repUsuario.getOne(id);
}
```

Usuário:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 50)
@NotNull(message = "O nome é obrigatório!")
@Length(min = 3, max = 200, message = "O nome deve conter entre 3 a 50 caracteres!")
private String nome;

@Column(name = "sobrenome", nullable = false, length = 100)
@NotNull(message = "O sobrenome é obrigatório!")
@Length(min = 3, max = 100, message = "O sobrenome deve conter entre 3 a 100 caracteres!")
private String sobrenome;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 200)
@NotNull(message = "O e-mail é obrigatório!")
@Length(min = 5, max = 200, message = "O e-mail deve conter entre 5 e 200 caracteres!")
private String email;

@Column(name = "senha", nullable = false, length = 20)
@NotNull(message = "A senha é obrigatória!")
private String senha;

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 20)
@NotNull(message = "O nome de usuário é obrigatório!")
@Length(max = 20, message = "O usuário deve conter entre 5 à 20 
caracteres!")
private String username;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario")
private List<Receita> receita;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario")
private List<Comentario> comentario;

//Getters e setters
```

Usuário controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {

@Autowired
private ServiceUsuario serviceUsuario;

@Autowired
private RepositoryUsuario repUsuario;

@GetMapping("/minhaConta")
public ModelAndView minhaConta(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("usuario/minhaConta");
    String username = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    Usuario usuario = serviceUsuario.encontrarPorUsername(username);
    mv.addObject("usuario", usuario);
    return mv;
}

@GetMapping("/alterar/{id}")
public String alterar(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    Usuario usuario = serviceUsuario.getOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);
    return "usuario/editarConta";
}

@PostMapping("/alterar")
public ModelAndView alterar(@Valid Usuario usuario, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
        mv.setViewName("usuario/editarConta");
        mv.addObject(usuario);
    } else {
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/usuario/minhaConta");
        repUsuario.save(usuario);
    }

    return mv;
}
```

Formulário de edição:

```
<h1 class="tituloRegist">Editar dados da conta:</h1>

            <div class="divRegist">

                <form class="form-horizontal formRegist" action="/usuario/alterar" method="POST" th:object="${usuario}">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputNome">Nome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNome" placeholder="Nome" th:field="*{nome}">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nome')}" th:errors="*{nome}" class="validation-message"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputSobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome"  th:field="*{sobrenome}">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('sobrenome')}" th:errors="*{sobrenome}" class="validation-message"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"  th:field="*{email}">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}" class="validation-message"></label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{senha}">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{username}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Poste o código da `RepositoryUsuario`

Comment: Postado @nullptr

Comment: Agora sua entidade `Usuario`

Comment: Pronto @nullptr

Comment: mais uma pergunta, você chegou a debugar e verificar se o usuário possui o id setado ao passar pela linha `repUsuario.save(usuario);` na sua service?

Answer (score -1):

No caso de uma alteração, vc precisa recuperar esse registro no banco de dados antes. Crie um método para alteração que recupera o usuário no banco de dados e ai sim salva a alteração. Por exemplo:

```
@Service
public class ServiceUsuario {

@Autowired
private RepositoryUsuario repUsuario;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public Usuario encontrarPorUsername(String Username) {
    return repUsuario.findByUsername(Username);
}

public void atualiza(Usuario usuario) {
    // Supondo que vc já tenha buscado o usuário antes de alterar, vc terá o id. 
    // Caso contrário vc pode buscar pelo username acrescentando um método na sua
    // interface (findByUsername)
    Usuario registro= repUsuario.findById(usuario.getId());
    if (Objects.nonNull(registro)) {
        registro.setNome(usuario.getNome());
        registro.setSobrenome(usuario.getSobrenome());
        registro.setEmail(usuario.getEmail());
        registro.setUsername(usuario.getUsername());
        registro.setSenha(usuario.getSenha());
        registro.setReceita(usuario.getReceita());
        registro.setComentario(usuario.getComentario());
        repUsuario.save(registro);
    } else {
        repUsuario.save(usuario);
    }
}

public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
    usuario.setSenha(passwordEncoder.encode(usuario.getSenha()));
    repUsuario.save(usuario);
}

public Usuario getOne(Long id) {
    return repUsuario.getOne(id);
}
```

Dessa forma quando vc quiser atualizar um registro, basta passar o Usuario no método de atualizar.

Queria deixar uma dica pra vc tbm caso queira: de uma olhada sobre o modelo REST, que contém princípios fundamentais e de boas práticas na construção de aplicações Web. O seu projeto fica devendo em algumas partes.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o problema esteja ocorrendo devido seu objeto `Usuario` não estar mais na sessão do Hibernate, então o comportamento padrão do `JPARepository` é aplicado:

> Saving an entity can be performed via the CrudRepository.save(…)-Method. **It will persist or merge** the given entity using the underlying JPA EntityManager. **If the entity has not been persisted yet Spring Data JPA will save the entity via a call to the entityManager.persist(…)-Method, otherwise the entityManager.merge(…)-Method will be called.**

Sugiro realizar a seguinte alteração:

```
@Transactional
public void salvar(Usuario usuarioAlteracao) {
    Usuario usuario = getOne(usuarioAlteracao.getId());
    usuario.setSenha(passwordEncoder.encode(usuarioAlteracao.getSenha()));
    repUsuario.save(usuario);
}
```

Isso irá colocar o usuário na sessão, e irá realizar o `merge` da entidade.

[Link da Documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)